# Why does javascript always fail silently?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am developing a react app, and I am using this stack:

```
webpack
babel
altjs
react
```

I am developing for the browser.
The problem is that most of the errors fail silently! Example, I was wrongly importing a resource that does not expose the right function, but javascript simply fail without let me knowing anything!

Is there a way to improve the way the browser comunicates errors?

EDIT: 
sorry but I was taking it for granted! I am using the console, but very few things are printed here!
Here is an example:

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react';
import {Route, DefaultRoute, NotFoundRoute} from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Route path="/" handler={AppCointainer}>
      <DefaultRoute handler={Login}/>
      <Route path="login" name="login" handler={Login}/>
      <Route path="signup" name="signup" handler={SignUp}/>
      <Route path="/reset-password" handler={ResetPassword}/>
    </Route>
  );
```

Here, I have clearly missed to import components like Login, Signup ecc... but it not tell me nothing in the browser! neither a generic error!

Comment: You see the errors in the browser console. What do you expect instead?

Comment: [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: @ciaoben *but very few things are printed here!* – again, what you do expect to see there?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Edited again sorry

Comment: @ciaoben Hmm, weird. That looks more like a bug. You can [open an issue here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new).

Comment: In fact in firefox it shows up

Answer (score 2):

You see the errors in the browser console. However, if you want to have a visual feedback that something went wrong, you can do that using the the `onerror` handler:

```js
window.onerror = function (e) {
    // run your custom stuff
    alert("Something went wrong!\n" + e);
};

setTimeout(function () {
  undefined.foo; // make an error appear
}, 100);
```

Comment: Could be useful on devices where you don't have access to the console, iPad for example.